# I can't install Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I got Mineecraft Launcher on Windows 8 64 - Bit but it does not install, it always fails when I try. I also got the latest version of Java also. How should I install it?  Should I install it on other versions of Windows or should I do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternative MC Launcher, that is shipped by Mojang to those, who have problems running installer. You can get it [here, on Mojang's download page](https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative).

> If you’re still having issues, you can try an older version of the Minecraft launcher. If given the option, save the file somewhere instead of running it, then double-click the program. This version **will require** you to have **Java** installed.

Try the second listed EXE file (or both of them if the one does not work, but that latter one works for my win 8 flawlessly), that should always work. Be sure you have Java installed correctly (64bit, and only latest version).

This launcher is the file you will execute every time. It will store all data in `%appdata%/.minecraft/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to have a good Internet Connection.** I've experienced something similar. *If the connection speed is poor, and unstable, the file(s) might only download partially.* Delete your (glitched), desired version from the Versions folder, and download it again, with a stable, good Internet Connection speed. (Try 500 kb/s+)

Comment: Where is the said folder ? That would be helpful imo.

Comment: It's in Users>(User Name)>Roaming>.minecraft. Please note that some of the folders are hidden. Enable viewing them. @Karlyr